# Paperclip callback before_post_process not working in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, mongoid4

I am working with Rails4 and mongoid-paperclip

```
mongoid-paperclip (0.0.9)
      paperclip (>= 2.3.6)
```

I wanted to change the file name, so my class is as below,

```
class Icon
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  has_mongoid_attached_file :icon,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :styles => {
      :small => { :geometry => "100x100"
    }
  }

  before_post_process :rename_avatar

  private

  def rename_avatar
    extension = File.extname(icon_file_name).downcase
    self.icon.instance_write(:file_name, "#{extension}")
  end

end
```

How to achieve this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I didn't mention the filename.

So modified method is,

```
def rename_avatar
    extension = File.extname(icon_file_name).gsub(/^\.+/, '')
    filename = icon_file_name.gsub(/\.#{extension}$/, '')
    self.icon.instance_write(:file_name, "#{filename}.#{extension}")
end
```